# how to change bing default search engine to google default search engine in windows 10

Tags: windows-10-preview

How do you change bing search engine to google search engine in windows 10 on microsoft edge(project spartan)?  I have looked in almost all settings nothing worked.

Comment: [It is possible to change the search provider.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_ie/cant-change-search-provider-in-project-spartan/c7750636-528f-4e93-980d-d21c5c017f5d).  What have you tried doing [exactly](http://www.intowindows.com/change-default-search-engine-in-edge/)?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what version you are on currently if you follow the screen shots below this should help :)

Select the options tab

[image]

Click on settings

[image]

Click on advanced settings

[image]

then scroll down and enter the address of the search engine you would like to run e.g. http://google.com

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: it doesn't have the "search in the address bar with" subtitle on mine

Comment: I found it but its in grey so I cant click on it

Comment: This means you're not on the "fast circle" so in a few days you should get an update which will allow you to edit the search engine :)

Comment: go to setings -> updates and security -> windows update -> advanced options -> get insider builds (change to fast) will take a while to take effect and you will need to check for updates etc. This will put you on the fast build and you should then be able to change the search engine. (if this is successful please don't forget to mark this as the answer so other people can use this fix)